# How to open incognito window using extension when user clicks a button on a webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on creating a voting site of some sorts. There will be a laptop at a physical location at my school and one of the pain points I need to solve is that since my site uses sign in with google, it becomes a hassle to sign everyone out and let the next person sign in, so I thought of opening an incognito tab to store session data when someone wants to vote, so that they just need to close the tab to clear their session data. I know that only an extension is allowed to open incognito tabs, and it would require the "tabs" permission, but how would I go about making it so that when someone clicks on the button on my site, my extension opens an incognito window for them to sign in?

let's say for instance when I click 
    `<button id="open_Incognito">Start Session</button>` it would open an incognito tab.

Comment: Please include some of the source code that you're working on, but having trouble with.

Comment: Declare a *content script* that runs on your site URL pattern, and in the content script add a click listener for the button element. In the listener send a message to your background script, which will finally open the  incognito tab. You'll need to read the extension overview introduction article in the official documentation.